# string separated by '\0' in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want a string that is separated by '\0'
This is my C++ string, i want this string to be in C#

```
#define DRIVERDLL "My.dll"
#define SETUPDLL "MySetup.dll"

NAME"\0""Driver="DRIVERDLL"\0""Setup="SETUPDLL"\0"
```

How to do this in C# ?

Comment: can u elaborate the output and input?

Comment: The above string will be input to a function i want to call

Comment: What exactly do you believe "\0" does in `C#`? It is not a null-terminator as in `C++`. What are you REALLY trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think could be something like:

```
string name = "name"
string driverdll = "My.dll"
string setupdll = "MySteup.dll";

string output = String.Format("{0}\\0Driver={1}\\0Setup={2}\\0", name, driverdll, setupdll).
```

Comment: Accepted without the \0... Remarkable

Comment: No I do want \0 in between, i removed acceptance

Comment: I adapted my code to your request.

Comment: Let me know if now this could fit your request :)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you try to accomplish.
Just a guess:

```
const string NAME = "...";
const string DRIVERDLL= "My.dll";
const string SETUPDLL= "MySetup.dll";
string s = NAME + "\0Driver=" + DRIVERDLL + "\0Setup=" + SETUPDLL + "\0";
```

Comment: After your code I tried printing s and it only gives me "Name", instead I want "Name Driver=My.dll Setup=MySetup.dll "

Comment: @ameybarve: You asked how to make a string containing `\0` characters. You did not say what you are doing with this string afterwards. Such a string has to be separated by `string.Split('\0')` before beeing displayed.

Answer (score 0):

as per your comment

```
string s = "NAME Driver=" + DRIVERDLL + " Setup=" + SETUPDLL + "\0";
```

Comment: Name must be a variable.

Comment: No that's what he didn't mention in the comment..."instead I want "Name Driver=My.dll Setup=MySetup.dll" ... just tying to help. he is himself not clear as to what he wants.

Comment: Yep, but the original code in c++ : NAME"\0""Driver="DRIVERDLL"\0""Setup="SETUPDLL"\0" means that NAME is a variable. :)

Comment: The above C++ code is not correct either..will giv compiler error

Comment: @StefanoBafaro and this is y I hate to answer silly questions in stackoverflow. There is no where #define(d) Name part. Thought may be by mistake he forgot to put Name under quotes. I will not edit/update my answer. You don't expect us to guess the question and answer them. Thanks for the downvote. :)

Comment: Yeah, you right, once i tried to imagine what a silly question was, and they told me after my answer if I'm a psycopath. I removed my answer :D.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually passing to the function is an array of strings.
Or, I suspect that the called function is expecting an array of strings.
By hand crafting a string that mimics an string [] will come back to you in a later stadium.

I suggest to do it the right way and marshal the strings properly.

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17450/Marshal-an-Array-of-Zero-Terminated-Strings-or-Str